# Server 2003 system config file corrupt, which is run inside of VMWare. How to fix?

Tags: vmware, windows-server-2003, ecc, sap

I'm using ecc 6.0 software in Server 2003 through VMWare, suddenly system32 config system file corrupt of Server 2003. Is there any process to fix this without uninstalling or change data of ecc6.0? how to repair Windows which is inside VMWare?

[image: Error message screenshot attached]

Comment: Create a ISO of the installation media, mount the ISO within the hypervisor, chnage boot order within the VMs bios configuration.  If you don't know how to do any of that, restore the virtual hdd, from a backup

Answer (score 0):

First, you must understand that this is a super-serious error. The Windows\System32\Config\SYSTEM contains the SYSTEM hive of your Windows Registry. It contains your hardware configuration and can only be regenerated by Windows Setup. (I have not seen this error in 10 years. It is impossible to damage SYSTEM through normal use.)

So, the solution comes down to this question: Do you have a backup or not? If yes, use it to restore SYSTEM. If not, I am afraid you are screwed.

Whatever you do, make sure the partition on which Windows Server 2003 is installed is an NTFS partition.